# WPF How to bind to a specific element in the Collection

Tags: wpf, data-binding, collections, element

I want to make a **binding to a specific element in the Collection**.
But I cannot figure out how to write the Binding.
This is the code:

```
public class MySource
{
 ..
 public string SomeProp;
 public ICollection<T> MyCollection;
 ..
}

this.DataContext = new MySource();

<TextBox Text={Binding SomeProp} />

<TextBox Text={Binding FIRST_ELEMENT_OF_THE_MyCollection} />
<TextBox Text={Binding SECOND_ELEMENT_OF_THE_MyCollection} />
<!--Ignore other elements-->
```

Try to replace those binding strings, please

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding MyCollection[0]}" /> 
<TextBox Text="{Binding MyCollection[1]}" />
```

Comment: And if you Need a property from inside the element, can you write this: {Binding MyCollection[0].Property}  ?

Comment: Yes. It should work in WPF. If not you can use two properties in ViewModel.